# Rendering components in pop up but props not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need to show my cart popping up with react bootstrap like this

**in Navbar.js**

```
<Offcanvas show={sideshow} onHide={handleClose} placement='end' style={{marginTop:'8vh'}}>
                    <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
                        <Offcanvas.Title>Keranjang</Offcanvas.Title>
                    </Offcanvas.Header>
                        <Offcanvas.Body>
                        <Cart />     ---------------------------//cart component
                    </Offcanvas.Body>
            </Offcanvas>
```

i do this in the app.js route

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

<Route path="/cart"  element={<Cart cartItems={cartItems} /> }/>
```

but somehow the cartItems not showing up in the pop up cart.

but when i make a new page for the cart and route it with Link in the navbar the cartItems show up

**in Navbar.js**

```
<Link to='/cart' className='navbar-link'>
                                          Go to cart
                 </Link>
```

anybody help would be appreciated, thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not pass `cartItems` props to your `Cart` component in `Offcanvas` component yet